# How to make registration in web applications userfriendly?

Tags: web-applications, openid, usability, registration, frontend

I'm designing a new web application and I'm aware that the process of registration (creating a profile) is really frustrating for the users (also to me) - everywhere we go, people should register. Some may even stop using your site, if you force them to register. The problem is that, I really need my users to be registered - I need to know their behavior in order to make the web site useful. Something like SO.

So, I need some advice how to make it painless for the users.

1. Is the OpenID option useful for the regular user? I love it, but are users used to this concept? Does it make sense to limit the creation of profiles only to OpenID providers?
2. Should I let my users surf and use the site and ask them to register in the last possible moment (using the core functionality) or I should promote the registration on the front page?
3. What other advice could you give me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- You should make openID an option, but not mandatory.
- Always have register/login links on every page.
- Put a few fields as possible on the register page. If you need more info from users, put it in an 'account' field they can fill out later.
- Take out as many steps as possible of the registering. For example, on Reddit.com, as soon as you register you are logged in to the account you just created.
- Yes, allow as much surfing without registering as possible so users can discover the value of the site.
- Provide a concise, clear, concrete statement of the primary benefits for the user of registering.

The quicker, easier, and more painless you make registering, the more likely people are to do it.

Elaboration of several of these guidelines at http://www.uie.com/articles/account_design_mistakes/